# UINavigationBar + iOS7 background image not setting properly

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I have set background image to `UINavigationController`.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NavigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And it appears like this. Why image is divided ? One can see the dark line. What was that ?

[image]

Comment: I think your background image NavigationBar.png height is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you see is the bottom of your image.

With iOS7, Navbar includes the status bar.

So one simple solution could be to just add 20px to the top of your background image.

Comment: Absolutely correct, your image should be 640 x 128 for Retina and 320 x 64 for 1x

Answer (score 0):

I tried your way with a image and I didn't faced your issue with image for navigation bar.
As shown below:-

[image: Demo]

Comment: Comments on how to replicate the issue should be commented, as this does not provide an answer to the correct the problem.

Comment: @iOSNoob I just tried to see if I face same issue as he is facing and Yes I should have commented but in comment I wouldn't able to show image(as I don't know how to show) so when for this post. Image prove's that I used what he did I didn't face any issue.

Comment: Also for him I was gng to suggest to change image size and give it a run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clean the project files (Shift+Command+K) and (Shift+Alt+Command+K). You may also want to try deleting the derived data under Window > Organizer > [Project Name] as well as deleting the app off the iOS device (stop project after build in xCode, then delete the app just like on iDevices). If that doesn't work, try changing the image size, or there may be something wrong with your image file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach to add the custom navigation bar with image is as follows:

Apply the following setting for respected view control:
**1.Select the View controller first in storyboard.**
**2. Go to Editor-> Embed in-> Navigation controller like as follow**

[image]

**3.Also do the following setting for respected view controller .**

[image]

**4. write the following code inside** 
**-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Image size should be proper without pixelated as per apple standards.
***i.e 
1) 320 X 44 For regular image
2) 640 X 88 for Retina image***

Hope this steps will work for you.
Thanks.